# Macbook wakes up immediately (OHC1)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have problems with my white unibody MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009, 10.10.1) - it can't go to sleep. I've read dozens of forum threads and could not fix it:

I've reseted PRAM/NVRAM. I've disconnected every USB device, disabled Bluetooth and Wi-fi but after about 15 seconds of black screen preparing-to-sleep it turns back on. I see the same lines in console logs:

```
kernel[0]: Wake reason: OHC1
kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
```

I suppose there's an issue with keyboard / trackpad but I don't know how to disable wakeup for this events. Waking by opening lid / pressing power button would be great.

I've set TTYSPreventSleep = 0 in com.apple.PowerManagement.plist with no noticable result.

Here is full Console output:

```
08.12.14 15:46:47,382 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:47.379098 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemWillSleep
08.12.14 15:46:47,385 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:47.385143 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
08.12.14 15:46:47,386 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:47.386069 PM [AirPlay] BTLE discovery removing all devices
08.12.14 15:46:47,396 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:47.396326 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
08.12.14 15:46:47,443 XPCKeychainSandboxCheck[1157]: Can't get sandbox fs extension for /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain, status=-1 errno=No such file or directory ext=(null)
08.12.14 15:46:47,458 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 6 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,459 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 6 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,465 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 7 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,465 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 7 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,473 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fb8bace1ad0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
08.12.14 15:46:47,473 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fdedb50ba10 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
08.12.14 15:46:47,482 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 8 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,482 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 8 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,483 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 9 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,484 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 9 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,507 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>:    NC Disabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:47,508 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>:    NC Disabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:47,539 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>:   DND Enabled: YES
08.12.14 15:46:47,539 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>:   DND Enabled: YES
08.12.14 15:46:47,539 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>: Updating enabled: NO   (Topics: (null))
08.12.14 15:46:47,539 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>: Updating enabled: NO   (Topics: (null))
08.12.14 15:46:47,574 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 10 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:47,575 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 10 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,538 WindowServer[299]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7f957b5f3120(2000), shield 0x7f957d828220(2001)
08.12.14 15:46:49,544 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 11 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,545 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 11 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,575 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 12 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,577 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 13 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,577 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 14 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,579 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 12 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,582 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 13 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,583 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 14 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,583 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 15 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,585 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 15 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:49,601 WindowServer[299]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7f957b5f3120(2000)[0, 0, 1280, 800] shield 0x7f957d828220(2001), dev [1280,800]
08.12.14 15:46:49,730 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.67" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
08.12.14 15:46:49,730 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.67" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
08.12.14 15:46:50,000 kernel[0]: PM response took 2216 ms (26, powerd)
08.12.14 15:46:50,000 kernel[0]: Failed to get hibernate image filename
08.12.14 15:46:50,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
08.12.14 15:46:50,000 kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
08.12.14 15:46:50,000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][ReceiveInterruptData] -- kIOReturnAborted, data size is 0, but data in buffer -- (data Length = 4, packet length = 6)  Data Content: 
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: OHC1
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::checkInterfacePowerState: Check _pwrOffThreadCall!
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: full wake promotion (reason 1) 22 ms
08.12.14 15:46:53,109 watchdogd[375]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
08.12.14 15:46:53,000 kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
08.12.14 15:46:53,547 WindowServer[299]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [1057087667987]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
08.12.14 15:46:53,548 WindowServer[299]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Ordering out authw 0x7f957b5f3120(2000), shield 0x7f957d828220(2001) (lock state: 2)
08.12.14 15:46:53,548 WindowServer[299]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: errs 0x0, 0x0
08.12.14 15:46:53,553 loginwindow[67]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion closeAuthAndReset:] | Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
08.12.14 15:46:53,580 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 16 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,605 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 17 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,606 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 16 connectx to 149.154.167.91:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,608 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 17 connectx to 149.154.175.50:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,620 discoveryd[51]: Basic DNSResolver UDNSServer:: PowerState is Wakeup
08.12.14 15:46:53,645 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 18 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,647 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 18 connectx to 149.154.171.5:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,709 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 19 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,715 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 19 connectx to 149.154.167.51:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,718 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 20 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,719 Telegram[473]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 20 connectx to 174.140.142.6:80@0 failed: Network is unreachable
08.12.14 15:46:53,815 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:53.814777 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
08.12.14 15:46:53,815 watchdogd[375]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
08.12.14 15:46:53,815 coreaudiod[382]: 2014-12-08 03:46:53.814996 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
08.12.14 15:46:53,819 sharingd[386]: 15:46:53.816 : Starting AirDrop server for user 501 on wake
08.12.14 15:46:54,000 kernel[0]: PM response took 219 ms (26, powerd)
08.12.14 15:46:54,133 sharingd[386]: 15:46:54.133 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
08.12.14 15:46:54,251 sharingd[386]: 15:46:54.250 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
08.12.14 15:46:54,332 sharingd[386]: 15:46:54.331 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
08.12.14 15:46:59,143 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fdedb4421b0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
08.12.14 15:46:59,145 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fb8bad86bb0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
08.12.14 15:46:59,161 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>:    NC Disabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:59,182 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>:   DND Enabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:59,182 imagent[430]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fdedb540140>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ac"
))
08.12.14 15:46:59,182 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>:    NC Disabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:59,192 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>:   DND Enabled: NO
08.12.14 15:46:59,193 identityservicesd[420]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fb8bad6fca0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity",
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ids",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity.public",
    "com.apple.madrid",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.auth",
    "com.apple.private.ac",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.idsremoteurlconnection",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.sms",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.maps",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.callhistorysync",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering"
))
08.12.14 15:47:05,202 loginwindow[67]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

% pmset -g

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power   -1
AC Power    -1*
Currently in use:
 womp                 0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        0
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

% pmset -g log

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====
UUID: F27753E8-65F8-47DB-B204-75FC7E293FD1
2014-12-08 14:43:23 +0200 Notification          Display is turned off
2014-12-08 14:43:23 +0200 Assertions            PID 72(hidd) Summary UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 00:06:39  id:0x900000452 [System: DeclUser kDisp]
2014-12-08 14:43:24 +0200 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep': Using AC (Charge:64%)        8 secs
2014-12-08 14:43:29 +0200 Wake Requests         [*proc=discoveryd request=Maintenance inDelta=6475]
2014-12-08 14:43:29 +0200 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(5459 ms)]
2014-12-08 14:43:32 +0200 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [NVDATesla driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1038 ms)] [powerd is slow(5472 ms)]
2014-12-08 14:43:32 +0200 Notification          Display is turned on
2014-12-08 14:43:32 +0200 Wake                  Wake [CDNVA] due to OHC1/HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:64%)
2014-12-08 14:43:32 +0200 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [en0 driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(441 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(464 ms)] [NVDATesla driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(516 ms)] [PRT0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(599 ms)]
```

% ioreg -rn OHC1 says: http://pastebin.com/KsBejaLj

I tried to enable forced hibernation to disk with sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 1, it does not help, here is one more console log: http://pastebin.com/FWXe4Y1x

Comment: I sympathise with your desire to try software configuration approaches like this.  However, I suspect it will be hard to do so without, say, working on the kernel.  Have you considered getting a hardware expert to look at it?  I know of one in my city who has helped with this kind of thing.  The problem may even be fixable by partial disassembly and cleaning.

Comment: I'm now on an island in Thailand and will be here for months. I don't trust my mac into hands of local specialists :)

Comment: I sympathise!  My next step would be to try Recovery mode.  If I had an external hard drive, I would try installing the OS onto that and see what happened using it as the startup disk.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar strange problems with macbook being unable to sleep, unable to wake up without restart, waking with the lid closed and draining down the battery to zero... phhew - so much headache((
Until I've finally tracked down the culprit - guess who? Telegram Desktop app!
I can also see it listed in your logs.
Try exiting the app and then put the laptop to sleep.
Tell me how it went.